# pycuda.gpuarray.dot() very slow at first call

Tags: python, cuda, pycuda, mailing-list

I have a working conjungate gradient method implementation in pycuda, that I want to optimize. It uses a self written matrix-vector-multiplication and the pycuda-native `gpuarray.dot` and `gpuarray.mul_add` functions

Profiling the program with `kernprof.py/line_profiler` returned most time (>60%) till convergence spend in one `gpuarray.dot()` call. (About .2 seconds)
All following calls of `gpuarray.dot()` take about 7 microseconds. All calls have the same type of input vectors (size: 400 doubles)

Is there any reason why? I mean in the end it's just a constant, but it is making the profiling difficult.
I wanted to ask the question at the pycuda mailing list. However I wasn't able to subscribe with an @gmail.com adress. If anyone has either an explanation for the strange `.dot()` behavior or my inability to subscribe to that mailing list please give me a hint ;)

Comment: An idle GPU frequently has a "start up delay" associated with it.   This can be due to waking up a GPU from sleep mode, or just the overhead associated with creating a GPU CUDA context. There are a variety of ways to mitigate this condition.  If the "first call" is in fact the first thing in your code to create a GPU context, then that might be a possible explanation.  You might try creating a dummy GPU operation ahead of the first operation you care about, ahead of any loops of course.

Comment: FWIW, subscribing to the list does work from GMail--I think. Check your spam folder for the subscription confirmation emails.

Comment: Thank you for the input, yes it was in the spam folder. Shouldnt use a mail provider of which I cant handle the interface I guess. Thank you and sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 2):

One reason would be that Pycuda is compiling the kernel before uploading it. As far as I remember thought that should happen only the very first time it executes it.

One solution could be to "warm up" the kernel by executing it once and then start the profiling procedure.